# How to replace x?x.y with x?.y in whole code in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

I need help with finding and replacing all code where i have **x?x.y** to replace with **x?.y**.
x and y are word(char[])

Comment: what is `word(char[])`?

Comment: in my case name of class for example :    **test ? test.open**  i need to replace with **test?.open**

Answer (score 1):

regex find

```
(\w+)\s*\?\s*\1\.(\w+)
```

replace

```
$1?.$2
```